# Inherit color but override opacity/transparency

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to inherit the color but override the opacity value? Here's an example in **pseudo** CSS:

```
.color-class {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
}

.lighten {
    background-color: rgba(inherit, inherit, inherit, .4);
}
```

Applied to

```
<div style="color-class">I am red</div>
<div style="color-class lighten">
    I am red and a little bit transparent
</div>
```

should result in a colored element and the other one being the same (inherited) color but with added transparency.

I basically want to have a CSS class that lightens (or darkens) the background color without changing the color value.

Comment: Are you using a css preprocessor? Sass, perhaps.

Comment: Great question.  I did not think it would be possible (yet), but maybe something for W3C to consider for CSS4/5.  (I would like to change the border-bottom opacity without having to respecify the entire colour - though maybe there is a way of doing that already?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution is to use pseudo element as background and simply control its opacity :

```css
div {
  padding: 40px;
}

.color-class {
  position: relative;
}

.color-class:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  opacity: 1;
  z-index:-1;
}

.lighten:before {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="color-class">I am red</div>
<div class="color-class lighten">
  I am red and a little bit transparent
</div>
```

Comment: I think this is a great idea, but lighten looks like it's being used as a utility class so it might be unreliable relying on pseudo-elements that might have already been used, OP's question about inheritance like that being possible, inheritance isn't happening here.

Comment: @FelipeWarrener-Iglesias inheritance here can be considered as the general term and not only the CSS term. So the OP want to achieve something using inherit and maybe he didn't think about other solution, so i provide another way that rely on the same principe which is keeping the color and changing opacity :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, this would **not** work because inherit takes the value from an elements **parent element** not its **sibling element**. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit

Secondly, the inherit keyword is a **property-value**. It cannot be used as an argument to a browser function (rgba) as the function itself is a property-value.

You also don't need to try this hard to enforce inheritance and re-usability, it will often bloat your code and make it over-engineered.

You would ideally have a set colour scheme and therefore be able to choose a fixed colour for lighten, considering you would be re-using this there isn't that much need to try and make it dynamic like that.

Other options you can go for if you REALLY want this functionality are using SASS/SCSS mix-ins to mimic this inheritance, JavaScript could also be an alternative however for what you're trying to achieve this would be really in-efficient.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that inherit relates to the parent not the sibling.

In my particular case, the color classes are written dynamically from database values, so the palette and preprocessor proposals probably won't work me.

I know I can't use `inherit` as an argument to `rgba()`. The snippet shall only illustrate the problem and therefore I've mentioned the code being pseudo. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, just use CSS variables. Let's say you have element with set background and you want to change its opacity.

```
<div class="bg-yellow">Yellow div</div>
```

Add new class for changing opacity:

```
<div class="bg-yellow bg-opacity-20">Yellow div</div>
```

And in your CSS:

```
.bg-yellow {
  --bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgba(255,230,0, var(--bs-opacity));
}
.bg-opacity {
  --bg-opacity: 0.2;
}
```

"255,230,0" is yellow btw...

And that's it, you can also manipulate this method as you want according to your needs.

```css
.bg-yellow {
  --bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgba(255,230,0,var(--bg-opacity));
}
.bg-opacity-20 {
  --bg-opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-yellow bg-opacity-20">Yellow div</div>
```