# convert opaque color to semi transparent color [blend mode]

Tags: css, browser, colors, color-blending

question in CSS area.

Let say I have as a given a opaque color `color= rgb(3, 169, 244)`

how can I use CSS `mix-blend-mode` or `background-blend-mode` to effect the alpha channel and draw this color in some variant of transparent as a `background-color`

thanks to everyone that help

Comment: Just stick an a, and you’ll get your alpha. `color:rgba(3,169,244,.4)`

Comment: I don' think that there is a blend mode that decrease alpha

Comment: @David the color is giving from the server. it can be any random color in any format

Comment: @TemaniAfif how much you know about that stuff ?

Comment: well, probably not too much but I know how the formula works (like described here: https://www.w3.org/TR/compositing-1/#blending) and if none of the color has an opacity I don't think you can end with a color that has opacity. but you can simulate this considering the main background color because adding more color from the background to the main color you will create the illusion of a transparent color

Comment: by the way, why you don't simply apply `opacity` to the color? Seems you are overcomplicating an easy thing

Comment: @TemaniAfif nice reference. I will read it.
 mean time I can control on the other colors that I want to blend with. so second color can be half opacity if it help .  about way not `opacity` or `filter:opacity` it effect all `element` not just the color

Comment: as I thought, it's an XY problee, you can overcome the opacity issue using other technique like using pseudo element where you apply the color and opacity (ex : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47831336/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/52851246/8620333 )

Comment: nice solution . maybe it can help here and there. I found another work arround with gradient